# Prevent duplicate Billing address creation in cutsomer_address_entity after customer checkout

Tags: magento2.3, sales-order, customer-address

I have noticed one thing. When placing an order from customer side, each time, the default billing address is duplicating in the customer_address_entity table.

I couldn't figure out where exactly the order placing and save customer address is taking place. Please give me some hint if you know about which all are the modules and files responsible for order placing and other action related to it in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es un bug de magento, en la versión 2.4.5 ya no he visto ese error, aquí hay una referencia de ello:

Apparently it is a magento error, in version 2.4.5 I have not seen that error anymore, here is a reference of it:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12827

Comment: Please leave answer in English